# DropShadow Legend

Tags: graphics, legending

I want to place a legend in a graph constructed with graphics primitives. Because some other elements use `DropShadowing[{6,-6}]` and `RoundingRadius->x` I want to use that in the frame of the legend, but I do not know how the `LegendFuntion->"Frame"` would allow customization. (I also want to control the `Thickness` of the frame.)

My effort to illustrate the problem is a `Rectangle` with `DropShadowing` and a legend that is a frame:

```
Legended[Graphics[{GrayLevel@.5, FaceForm@None, EdgeForm@Thick,
   Rectangle[corner = {8, ySize = 5} (sclg = .8), -corner], 
   FaceForm[White], DropShadowing[{6, -6}], 
   Rectangle[{-2, 0}, {0, 3}, RoundingRadius -> .1]}
  , ImageSize -> 1667], 
 Placed[PointLegend[{Red, Blue, Red, Blue, Red, Blue, Red, Blue, Red, 
    Blue}, {"One", "Two", "One", "Two", "One", "Two", "One", "Two", 
    "One", "Two"}, LegendMarkers -> Graphics@Rectangle[], 
   LegendMarkerSize -> 15, LegendFunction -> "Frame", 
   LegendLabel -> "Legend", 
   LegendLayout -> "Row"], {.15, .81}]]
```

Thanks for your thoughts! (I shall grant you that the documentation contains a sample function for creating a drop-shadow legend, but that seems not to automatically adjust size as the legend changes and uses neither `DropShadowing` nor `RoundingRadius` which would likely simplify things.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ClearAll[dropShadow]
Options[dropShadow] = 
  {RoundingRadius -> 5, frameBackground -> White,  FrameStyle -> Gray};

dropShadow[args___, opts : OptionsPattern[{dropShadow, Graphics}]] := 
  Module[{frameOptions = Thread[{RoundingRadius, Background, FrameStyle} -> 
        OptionValue[{RoundingRadius, frameBackground, FrameStyle}]]}, 
    Graphics[{DropShadowing[args], Inset[Framed[#, frameOptions]]}, 
     ImageSize -> Automatic -> Rasterize[#, "RasterSize"], 
     FilterRules[{opts}, Except[Options[dropShadow]]]]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
colors = {Red, Green, Blue, Orange};
labels = {"label1", "label2", "label3", "label4"};

SwatchLegend[colors, labels, LegendFunction -> dropShadow[]]
```

[image]

```
SwatchLegend[colors, labels, LegendFunction -> dropShadow[{6, -6}]]
```

[image]

```
SwatchLegend[colors, labels, LegendMargins -> 10, 
 LegendMarkerSize -> 45, LabelStyle -> 32, 
 LegendFunction -> dropShadow[{20, -25}, 10, Green]]
```

[image]

```
SwatchLegend[colors, labels, LegendLayout -> "Row", 
 LegendMargins -> 10, LegendMarkers -> "Bubble", 
 LegendMarkerSize -> 45, LabelStyle -> 14, 
 LegendFunction -> 
  dropShadow[{10, -10}, frameBackground -> LightGray, 
   Background -> LightBlue, ImagePadding -> 10]]
```

[image]

```
Row[Append[#[colors, labels, LegendFunction -> 
    dropShadow[{6, -6}, frameBackground -> LightBlue]] & /@ 
      {PointLegend, LineLegend}, 
  BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {0, 10}}, LegendLayout -> "Row", 
   LegendFunction -> 
     dropShadow[{6, -6}, frameBackground -> LightBlue, ImagePadding -> 30]]], 
  Spacer[10]]
```

[image]